# Istance of variable with VueJS and Node-RED

Tags: vue.js, node-red

I'm developing a simple app with Node-RED, VueJS and Waton API.
I wrote following code in a flow wired to HTTP OUTPUT.
The problems start when I try to visualize the web page.
The hint message change, the question message no.

Why I can't see the questions?

Maybe is a problem of scope?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Find Funds</title>

  <!-- Include VueJS Framework -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

  <!-- Include VueJS Resource -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>

  <!-- Include W3.CSS Framework -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

  <!-- Include Google Icon -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="w3-cyan"> 
  <div id="app" class="w3-contenitor w3-round w3-white w3-display-middle">
    <span clas="w3-row">
      <h1 class="w3-margin w3-threequarter">{{getQuestion()}}</h1>
    </span>
    <span class="w3-row">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="w3-margin" v-model="currentAnswer">
        <i class="material-icons w3-margin" v-on:click="addAnswer()">send</i>
        <i class="material-icons w3-margin" v-bind:title="getHint()">help_outline</i>
      </form>
    </span>
  </div>

<script id="jsbin-javascript">
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    questions: ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"],
    hints: ["first hint", "second hint", "third hint", "fourth hint", "fifth hint"],
    answers: [],
    currentAnswer: ""
  },
  methods: {
    getQuestion: function(){
      return this.questions[this.count];
    },
    getHint: function(){
      return this.hints[this.count];
    },
    addAnswer: function(){
      this.answers.push(this.currentAnswer);
      this.count++;
      this.currentAnswer = "";

      if(this.count >= this.questions.length){
        // some code
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks  ok, are you sure there is no other framework in your setup is interfering with vue.js? simplest thing would be to put a debugger in the getQuestion() method and see what exactly is going on

Comment: I tried file html on PC, and code works.I have this problem when i put the code in the flow.

Comment: Your `console.log` messages are breaking things because you left off `this` from the variable names.

Comment: Thank you, now with console.log i can see the value of variable. This means that they are inizialized... But why i can't see the question in <h1>....</h1>? There is some comand to see the scope of variables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code as presented except for the failure to include `this` on the variables in your `console.log` statements.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    questions: ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"],
    hints: ["first hint", "second hint", "third hint", "fourth hint", "fifth hint"],
    answers: [],
    currentAnswer: ""
  },
  methods: {
    getQuestion: function(){
      return this.questions[this.count];
    },
    getHint: function(){
      return this.hints[this.count];
    },
    addAnswer: function(){
      this.answers.splice(this.count, 1, this.currentAnswer);
      this.count++;
      if(this.count >= this.questions.length){
        // some code
        this.count = 0;
      }
      this.currentAnswer = this.answers[this.count];

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Include VueJS Framework -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<!-- Include VueJS Resource -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>

<!-- Include W3.CSS Framework -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<!-- Include Google Icon -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app" class="w3-contenitor w3-round w3-white w3-display-middle">
  <span clas="w3-row">
      <h1 class="w3-margin w3-threequarter">{{getQuestion()}}</h1>
      <small>{{getHint()}}</small>
    </span>
  <span class="w3-row">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="w3-margin" v-model="currentAnswer">
        <i class="material-icons w3-margin" v-on:click="addAnswer()">send</i>
        <i class="material-icons w3-margin" v-bind:title="getHint()">help_outline</i>
      </form>
    </span>
    <div v-for="a, i in answers">{{i}}. {{a}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using console and debug flow of NodeRED, I'm sure that code works. Only problem is {{ getQuestion() }} I can't see the question. This is my app https://find-funds.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/app .

Comment: Your app is not putting anything in the `h1`. I can only say it's not due to anything you posted here. Try putting something like `'Some constant'` instead of `getQuestion()` in the brackets and see if you get anything.